# How can i use two collection in single reactive table?

Tags: javascript, sorting, meteor

I am using [aslagle:reactive-table](https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table) package for getting data from two collection but its not working. my anyone help me out with using two collection in reactive table.

**Example:**
I have two collection A and B : 
Collection A consist of fields C1, C2, C3
Collection B consist of fields C4, C5 and C6

I want to display C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6 in a single table
with all columns sortable and searchable ...

Please tell help me for solution or if i can use another package for this

Thanks in advance...:

Comment: I flagged this as a duplicate, however if you are looking to accomplish this with just `reactive-table`, you are going to be out of luck unless you do this on the server side with a single collection. You would have to add a `CollectionA.after.insert()`, `CollectionA.after.update()`, `CollectionB.after.insert()`, and `CollectionB.after.update()` to then insert into a third collection, and then pass that collection to `reactive-table`. If you don't want to do it on the client side, I don't think yo ucan use that package.

Comment: @BrettMcLain - related to collection merging but not a dupe as this question is specific to reactive-table and there is actually a clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use [virtual columns](https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table#virtual-columns) to lookup the value from the foreign collection. For example if you start by defining a table of documents from collection *A*:

```
{
    key: 'bId', // the key name that you use to point to B from A
    fieldId: 'c4', // must be unique
    label: 'Explosive Material',
    fn: function (value, object) {
      return B.findOne({ _id: value }).c4;
    }
}
```